# Fix bash_profile to Develop Ruby on Rails Apps

Tags: command-line, bash, ruby, rails

I just installed Ruby and Rails stuff on my machine, and start to learn.

But every time I close the Terminal and re-open it, I have to re-type the command **. ~/.bash_profile** in order to run Rails commands properly...

How can i fix this, to close and re-open the Terminal, ready to develop my Rails apps?

Comment: How have you installed the "RoR stuff"? Using `apt-get` or through `rvm`? Which errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your terminal is not invoking the shell as *login shell*. This inhibits the sourcing of your `~./bash_profile`.

To fix this issue fix the terminal configuration.

For `gnome-terminal` e.g. look at this screenshot: [image]

Comment: Making the terminal start a login shell every time defeats the purpose of having a login shell. It'd be better to put the configuration on the correct file instead, as in Naha's answer.

Comment: @ScottSeverance the official RVM docs say you need to run it as a login shell. Yes, putting it in the other files works, but it can be a pain later on to debug problems that arise because of it not being a login shell m

Comment: In that case, logging out and back in would seem to be to proper solution. I haven't read the RVM docs, bit it seems a little silly for them to need a login shell.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your PATH varible inside "**~/.bashrc**" file, which gets executed every time a bash shell is started.

Thus the PATH to your rails bin directory is set and every command inside that is visible in your shell.

I hope this would help.

Comment: how can i do it, @Naha? my ~/.bashrc only shows me: PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin

Comment: @PauloZanetti In that case you can find the PATH set in your ~/.bash_profile and add it here. In general, if you have some executable in a dir to be used as a command without specifying absolute path, add its absolute path with the file name in PATH variable.